# macro to generate template definition

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to generate many definition of a `template struct`

```
#define REGISTER_FUNCTOR(type, func) \
  template <OWNER> \
  struct writeCharFunctor { \
    void operator(PropInfoType::iterator& it, PdxWriterPtr pw)() { \
      MemberProperty<OWNER,type> *ptr = (MemberProperty<OWNER, type> *)it->second; \
      const char *propertName = ptr->m_propertyName.c_str(); \
      if ( !ptr->m_getterFn ) { \
        throw; \
      } \
      pw->###func(propertName,(pOwner->*(ptr->m_getterFn))()); \
    } \
  };

  REGISTER_FUNCTOR(char,writeChar);
```

But I am getting compiler error `error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'OWNER'`
My function names are different for each type, so cannot use directly template parameter ( or there is way to do this )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that should be `template <class OWNER>` or `template <typename OWNER>`